# why is group a wrong alias in postgres + Django for auth_group table

Tags: django, postgresql-12

Why is that the following simple query does not work (Using Django in the backend)

```
# select group.name from auth_group as group;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: select group.name from auth_group as group;
```

while the following works

```
# select groupd.name from auth_group as groupd;
     name      
---------------
 FO Admin Role
 admin
 alice
 bob
(4 rows)
```

What is wrong with using `group` as an alias ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (`group by`)  and thus can't be used as a regular identifier.

You *could* use it by enclosing it in double quotes `as "group"` but I strongly recommend to use some other name.